How to detect if there is any value which have space inside double quotes (using jq or in linux)?
Sample json data as below:
There are multiple lines in a file. Few lines with NOK sample and rest are OK.
How to identify such problematic lines which have spaces?
NOK:
[[{"PK":"ABCD||1000000","id":"ABCD||1000000","chargingRules":{"code":[{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET"}}},{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"VR_0_50"}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.IMS"}},{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVDest_Country"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":0,"value":"IND"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"VOICE","schemaVersion":0},{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":**"ABCD_BUCKET "**}}},{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"SR_0_12"}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.SMS"}},{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVDest_Country"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":0,"value":"IND"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"SMS","schemaVersion":0},{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"DR_0_08"}}},{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":**"ABCD_BUCKET "**}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.PS"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"DATA","schemaVersion":0}],"codeMode":1,"items":[{"componentId":"SR_0_12","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1},{"componentId":"VR_0_50","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1},{"componentId":"ABCD_BUCKET","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":2,"type":1},{"componentId":"DR_0_08","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1}],"splitChFlag":0,"tariffName":"ChargingRules"}}],[{"Status":0}]]

OK:
[[{"PK":"PQRS||2000000","id":"PQRS||2000000","chargingRules":{"code":[{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET"}}},{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"VR_0_50"}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.IMS"}},{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVDest_Country"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":0,"value":"IND"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"VOICE","schemaVersion":0},{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET"}}},{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"SR_0_12"}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.SMS"}},{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVDest_Country"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":0,"value":"IND"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"SMS","schemaVersion":0},{"actions":[{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Rate","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Rate","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"DR_0_08"}}},{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET"}}}]},{"attributeInfo":{"name":"Tax-Selection","resultContext":"RATING"},"parameters":[{"name":"Data","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"Tax"}}}]}],"condContainer":{"conditions":[{"criteria":{"name":"Get-Variable","sourceContext":"VARIABLES"},"criteriaArgs":[{"name":"Name","value":{"type":0,"value":"GVCallType"}}],"operator":0,"value":{"type":3,"value":"CallType.PS"}}],"operator":0},"modifiedDate":1725306076363,"rulename":"DATA","schemaVersion":0}],"codeMode":1,"items":[{"componentId":"SR_0_12","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1},{"componentId":"VR_0_50","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1},{"componentId":"ABCD_BUCKET","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":2,"type":1},{"componentId":"DR_0_08","isPrimary":1,"isRoot":0,"overrideInst":0,"subType":6,"type":1}],"splitChFlag":0,"tariffName":"ChargingRules"}}],[{"Status":0}]]

Difference:
..."parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET "}}},...
..."parameters":[{"name":"Target","value":{"data":{"type":0,"value":"ABCD_BUCKET"}}},...


What do you mean by “value” exactly? Are you referring to the value of a key named "value"? And do you want the line numbers of the JSON entitiesthat have the relevant matching criterion, or some other indicator?

I mean there should not be space anywhere between double quotes like this is the problematic one "ABCD_BUCKET "

To print out the .value strings containing blanks:
jq 'def stroll:
      if type == "object" 
      then if (.value | type == "string" and test(" ")) then .value
           else .[] | stroll
           end
      elif type == "array" then .[] | stroll
           else empty
      end;  
    stroll' input.json

If you also want the line numbers, replace then .value with something like:
    then [input_line_number, .value]


You just want to single those lines out?
As long as there aren't newlines embedded (which is absolutely a possibility in JSON) you could just use grep.
$: grep -no ': *"[^"]* [^"]*"' file
1::"ABCD_BUCKET "

jq is almost certainly safer, but which jq are you using?

There are two downvotes here. If you have a moment, please comment why; I'll try to fix it, or just delete the answer if it's counterproductive.
